# Does Xcode 9 GIT integration support stashes?

Tags: git, xcode9, git-stash

I've always used SourceTree for my GIT interactions, but recently decided to try staying within Xcode for everything. However, I can't find everything.  For instance, while I see branches, tags and remotes, I don't see stashes. Are they there?

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question, but merely another take at it since you are switching UI anyway. Assuming that you understand the basics and that you are somewhat comfortable using the command line, using plain Git without a GUI is superior in many ways, and as a bonus it will be easier to ask experienced users for help. If you use Git daily I strongly encourage you to have a look.

Comment: @jsageryd yeah, I know about the command line, but I’ve always preferred GUIs because I’m visual. I like being able to switch views or interactively review (or even revert changes) on a line by simply clicking on that line. Knowing the command line is good, but after developing for 30+ years, I’ve always found a good GUI to be superior, at least for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode 9 does not have support for stashes.

**Xcode 11 Update**

Xcode 11 adds support for Git stashes. Choose Source Control > Stash Changes to stash changes. You can view your stashes from Xcode's source control navigator. The stashes are in the Stashed Changes folder.

[image]

Comment: added in xcode 11. See also [Xcode 11 Git Stashing](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-11-git-stashing/)